# "fool" or "dumb" to describe an easy tool?

Tags: word-choice

I want to recommend an easy tool. Anyone can use it without a learning curve. What words are proper to emphasize its simplicity and usability? "A dumb tool", is it good?

Comment: Neither of these is appropriate. If you look up *fool tool* or *dumb tool* none of the results have the meaning you intend.

Comment: @GArthurBrown Any good/normal expressions for it? Thanks

Comment: On second glance, *dumb tool* does seem to be used in the computing/engineering field. But this is jargon that would be best discussed in another forum.

Comment: Is "a dead-simple tool" better?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to convince others to share your opinion about the tool? IMO it would be better to tell them facts they'd find useful for forming their own judgements. What, specifically, makes this tool easier than alternative tools? As a user, I'd be more impressed to read that e.g. the buttons were clearly marked, the handle can be operated by someone with dexterity problems, the messages on the screen are easy to read and understand, or whatever.

Comment: Is this an actual tool, or an app?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the word **foolproof**.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/foolproof)

> Incapable of going wrong or being misused.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foolproof)

> so simple, plain, or reliable as to leave no opportunity for error, misuse, or failure

Comment: Chambers defines **foolproof** as "infallible; guaranteed not to cause damage or injury if misued". That is, as I see it, "reliable; safe". Not the same as "easy to use". In any case, if the OP tells users that the tool is "foolproof", they might think they are being called fools if they find the documentation inadequate for teaching them how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Genius tool

You need the opposite of dumb or fool, for this!

I would use 'genius tool' - which implies that the tool makes you into a genius - and also that the tool is 'a genius' in its own right and can do very clever things for you easily.

Here's two examples of how to use it like that:

- This new pot riveter is a genius tool for anyone who wants to put the handle back on their saucepan quickly and easily without hurting their fingers.
- This new rice cooker is a genius tool for anyone who wants to create delicious fluffy rice in moments while never burning the bottom of the pan.

Genius - definition
very great and rare natural ability or skill

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/genius

Comment: I've never encountered this, and would not interpret it to mean that the tool is easy to use. To me, it suggests that the tool is a great idea or is badly needed or that it fills a very specific niche. This phrasing strikes me as very odd, I would probably read this under the interpretation that the author had intended to use the word "ingenious" instead.

Comment: Here’s an example ‘The top 10 genius tools for your Dad’ written by a tool company, called General Tools. https://generaltools.com/blog/top-10-genius-tools-for-your-dad/   Make this Father’s Day the most memorable one yet with the below Top 10 Genius Tools from General. Any Dad will feel like a genius on the job whether he is a professional or a DIYer with General Tools.